# Put data in a 2d-array and print it to a predifined place

Tags: java, arrays

I don't really know how I can put data (a cell based on row and column + the value put in the cell) in a 2d-array (so what I put in my array is wrong as you can see) and then show that data on the correct place. 3 examples of data are written. I created the table with the for-loop. I'm still looking for the solution, so if I find it i'll say it here too. Thanks.

Edit, I recreated the table as you suggested, the reason I can't just make a method put(int row, int col, double value) is because I want to use a string cell, which combines the 2. If I want to put a value in a cell the program needs to recognise that sh.put("11",1) needs to put value 1 in cell 11, so row 1 column 1.

```
public class SpreadSheet{
   String[][] sheet; // Data + formules sheet
   String[][] values; // copy sheet 
   private int data;
   private int formules;  

   public static void main(String []args){
      SpreadSheet sh = new SpreadSheet(4, 6, 15, 2);
      sh.put("11", 1); // String cell, double value
      sh.put("12", 2); // String cell, double value
      sh.put("test", 3); // String cell, double value
      sh.put('2', 2); // char col, double value
      sh.put(3, "test"); // int row, String value
   } 

   public SpreadSheet(final int rows, final int columns, final int width, int precision) {
       this.sheet = new String [4][6];
        for (int ir = 0; ir < rows; ir++){
            System.out.print(ir + 1);
            System.out.print(" ");
            for (int ic = 1; ic < columns; ic++) {
                //System.out.print(" ");
                put(2, 3);
                printSheet();
                for (int iw = 1; iw < (width); iw++) {
                    //System.out.print(iw); // test width
                }
                System.out.print("|");
            }   
            System.out.println();
        }
   }
   private void printSheet() {
      System.out.print(sheet[data][formules]);
   }
   /*private void put(int row, int col, double value){
   }*/
   private void put(String cell, double value){
       sheet[0][0] = String.valueOf(value);
   }
   private void put(int col, double value){
       sheet[0][0] = String.valueOf(value);
   }
   private void put(int row, String value){
       sheet[1][0] = String.valueOf(value);
   }
}
```

Comment: sh.put("2", 2); // char col, double value is not correct you need to do sh.put('2', 2); // char col, double value. I cannot understand you problem can you say what you enter and what should be the expected result.

Comment: `sheet` and `values` are both set to `null`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to invoke `put(char...` instead of `put(String...` you need to put the char in single quotes.

Moreover, you are trying to populate your 2d array before ever initializing it.

In the beginning of your constructor you need to put something like:

```
this.sheet=new String[rows][columns]
```

I can't help but notice your overloads of `put` are either overly cute or downright wrong, depending on what you are trying to accomplish. why don't you just have:

```
 public void put(int row, int col, double value)
   {
       sheet[row][col] = String.valueOf(value);
   }
```

edit: a few things that are still wrong with your code:

1- you are now correctly initializing `sheet` in your constructor but you forgot about `values`

2- you are allowed to initialize 2d arrray bound with `final int` but you are still hardcoding the dimensions with disregard to what values are passed in the constructor

3- I advise against using `String.valueOf(value)` when you know the type of value. You will not always know which overload of `String.valueOf` is being called and you are relying on the compiler to pick the appropriate function for you. This is unnecessary and can be dangerous.

for example instead of

```
   private void put(int col, double value)
   {
       sheet[0][0] = String.valueOf(value); 
   }
```

do:

```
   private void put(int col, double value)
   {
       sheet[0][col] = Double.toString(value); 
       //just convert double to String, nothing fancy
   }
```

and instead of

```
private void put(int row, String value)
{
  sheet[1][0] = String.valueOf(value);
}
```

try for:

```
private void put(int row, String value)
{
  sheet[row][0] = value; //value is already a String
}
```

Now, as for using a `java.lang.String` object to specify a coordinate in a 2d array, this is completely ill advised! Sure you can get cute and have something like:

```
private void put(String cell, double value)
{
    int i =Integer.parseInt( cell.substring(0, 1));
    int j =Integer.parseInt( cell.substring(1));
    sheet[i][j] = Double.toString(value);
}
```

But I do not recommend doing it this way. 
This code of course will fail miserably if `String cell` is not EXACTLY 2 characters long (which effectively rules out the possibility of having dimensions greater than 9)

If you want to pass in a 2d coordinate I would recommend you use an `ArrayList` of size 2

Comment: I recreated the table as you suggested, the reason I can't just make a method put(int row, int col, double value) is because I want to use a string, cell, which combines the 2. If I want to put a value in a cell the program needs to recognise that sh.put("11",1) needs to put value 1 in cell 11, so row 1 column 1.

Comment: so its working now? if you initialize your 2d Arrays properly they wont be set to null

Comment: No, I mean they are not null, it shows for example 3,0. It just seems I can't get the value at the correct place in the table like I said.

Comment: remember to initialize values as well. not just sheet. OK please think about the code that you are writing. I am going to edit my answer to give you more clues